# Neo4j loop for all children

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In Neo4j I got the following nodes:
[image]

As you can see, they are siblings connected by relationships as NEXT or NEXT_SIBLING; moreover, the first and last child are connected to the father by FIRST_CHILD_OF and LAST_CHILD_OF.

I simply want to find a way to cycle them in order to create a single string which is "A B C D".

Is there a Cypher query capable of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Creating your model

For the ease of possible further answers and solutions I note my graph creating statement:

```
CREATE
  (ormText:OrmText {name: 'orm_Text'})<-[:FIRST_CHILD_OF]-(letterA:Letter {name: 'A'}),
  (letterA)-[:NEXT]->(letterB:Letter {name: 'B'}),
  (letterA)-[:NEXT_SIBLING]->(letterB),
  (letterB)-[:NEXT]->(letterC:Letter {name: 'C'}),
  (letterB)-[:NEXT_SIBLING]->(letterC),
  (letterC)-[:NEXT]->(letterD:Letter {name: 'D'}),
  (letterC)-[:NEXT_SIBLING]->(letterD),
  (letterD)-[:LAST_CHILD_OF]->(ormText);
```

[image: graph]

### Solution

```
MATCH
  letterPath = (startLetter)-[:NEXT|NEXT_SIBLING*]->(endLetter)
WHERE 
  (startLetter)-[:FIRST_CHILD_OF]->(:OrmText)<-[:LAST_CHILD_OF]-(endLetter)
WITH nodes(letterPath) AS letterNodes
UNWIND letterNodes AS letterNode
RETURN DISTINCT letterNode.name AS letterName;
```

The second line detects the `startLetter` as first child of `orm_Text` and the `endLetter` as last child of `orm_Text`.
In line five the path between the start and end letter is calculated, its nodes were extracted in line six. Line seven creates singles nodes and line eight finally returns the result.

**Note:** By writing `-[:NEXT|NEX_SIBLING*]->` a relationship of type `NEXT` *or* `NEXT_SIBLING` is valid for a match. If your requirement only need one specific type, remove the other and the `|`.

### Result

```
╒════════════╕
│"letterName"│
╞════════════╡
│"A"         │
├────────────┤
│"B"         │
├────────────┤
│"C"         │
├────────────┤
│"D"         │
└────────────┘
```

---

## Extension

If you prefer your output in a single `String` instead of a list of node names have a look at the following solution.

### Solution

```
MATCH
  letterPath = (startLetter)-[:NEXT|NEXT_SIBLING*]->(endLetter)
WHERE 
  (startLetter)-[:FIRST_CHILD_OF]->(:OrmText)<-[:LAST_CHILD_OF]-(endLetter)
WITH nodes(letterPath) AS letterNodes
RETURN DISTINCT reduce(s=head(letterNodes).name, n in tail(letterNodes) | s+" -> "+n.name) AS letterString;
```

### Result

```
╒══════════════════╕
│"letterString"    │
╞══════════════════╡
│"A -> B -> C -> D"│
└──────────────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand the approach and I'm sure it's correct, but I got the error "Variable `ormText` not defined ". Even creating a new MATCH at the beginning with this var, returns 0 records. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Wall Sorry, it was my fault. During the optimization something slightly screwed up. I corrected both `MATCH` statements, now the rendered result should be displayed again.

Comment: @Wall I hope it works for you now and solves your challenge?

Comment: Thanks, the query is fine, but I also need to use the ormText variable in the RETURN clause.
So I do: RETURN DISTINCT ormText.id, reduce...ecc
but I got the error: "Variable ormText not defined "
Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: To return properties of the `OrmText` label, you must specify the node variable first and loop it through each `WITH` clause. Solution: `MATCH letterPath = (ormText:OrmText)<-[FIRST_CHILD_OF]-(startLetter:Letter)-[:NEXT|NEXT_SIBLING*]->(endLetter:Letter)-[LAST_CHILD_OF]->(ormText) WITH nodes(letterPath) AS letterNodes, ormText.name AS ormTextName WITH filter(x IN letterNodes WHERE NOT (x:OrmText)) AS letterNodes, ormTextName RETURN DISTINCT reduce(s = head(letterNodes).name, n IN tail(letterNodes) | s + ' -> ' + n.name) AS letterString, ormTextName;`.

Comment: This results in `{ "letterString“: "A -> B -> C -> D" }, { "ormTextName" : "orm_Text" }`.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much.